# .net Web.Debug.config transform is not working

Tags: asp.net

I have the following in my Web.config

```
<exceptionless Enabled="true" apiKey="XXXX"></exceptionless>
```

and my Web.Debug.config has this

```
<exceptionless Enabled="false" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(Enabled)"></exceptionless>
```

Now when I debug my application and set a breakpoint on the code

```
var exceptionless = ExceptionlessClient.Default;
```

I inspect the values and Enabled does not get changed to false. How can I determine if the Web.Debug.config transform is even being used?

Comment: to use Web.Debug.config you will need to publish application in mode set to debug

Comment: That's what I have it set to

Answer (score 1):

Web.Config transforms only happen during a Publish or Package.  So, you will only see the change take affect in a published application.

Comment: That's strange, as we other transforms that work (Such as AppSettings.<MACHINE_NAME>.config) when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Even if after publishing it does not transform check in your .csporj file if transform is set. 
Open the .csproj in a text editor and check if below XML if there, if not just add and try

```html
  <Target Name="Publish">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\Web.config" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following to my XML file

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
```

Comment: Perhaps we should add a section about this to the exceptionless wiki or maybe one of the sample apps .